# VC++ LPTSTR Error

Tags: visual-c++, exception

I am doing a project on firewall. I am not familiar very much with VC++. Though I am much sound in java and c#. But for my project sake I needed to create a dll. For what I exported 2 pre-written .h and .cpp files to my c++ project. But it is giving error on compile. Saying can not convert to LPTSTR etc. But it is compiling perfectly in the other project from where I fetch those files.
Am I missing something? Please help.

Thanks.

ERRORS:

Code:

driverPath = (LPTSTR)malloc(strlen(path) + 1);

Error:

'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *'

Code:

strcpy(driverPath, path);

Error:

strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPTSTR' to 'char *'

Comment: Show the relevant code and the exact error message. Currently, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I think you are on a Unicode platform so `TCHAR` (which is what `LPCTSTR` is a pointer to) is typedef of `wchar`. This has been answered in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287879/why-cant-convert-tchar-to-char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project configuration Character Set is probably set to Unicode. In the project settings, change your project configuration Character Set to `Not Set` or use `const TCHAR *` instead of `const char *`